# php can't include muliple files

Tags: php, include

I've got two php files which have prices of products from websites and display the prices fine, but I want to include both these files on one page and it only seems to display only the first in the list. I've test both separately and they both work fine.

```
<?php 
include('PricePage1.php'); 
include('PricePage2.php'); 
?>
```

Can anyone help? I'm also using the simple_html_dom.php in each file as well

Here is what is in the PricePage1.php:

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html("http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/4489263.htm");

foreach($html->find('ul.product-price-data li.price') as $element)

echo
    <a href='http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/4489263.htm' target='_blank'><img src='Images/argos.png'> </img>".$element->innertext()."</a></h3><br>" ;
?>
```

Comment: We would need to see what's in the files.

Comment: there is probably some code at the end of the first file that breaks the code of the second file

Comment: I've added the file, sorry for the format it has turned out like but this is what it looks like for both files

Comment: you are missing `"`at the end and beginning of your `echo` commando

Comment: Sorry that was already on there, must have deleted it when I was posting the code. The prices do echo out, it just can't seem to display the two files.

Comment: You need to be more specific and accurate when posting code. People will lose interest in your question when you don't supply the correct code you work with. The code that is in your question right now is just one file, instead of two, and it has an error.

Comment: Could you please provide all relevant code for us, otherwise we will not be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes for your echo and also your opening and closing curly braces for your 'foreach'.

Comment: this is more a comment than an answer and the error has already been mentioned. You don't need curly braces if there is only one command in the foreach loop

Comment: I can't delete my answer from my phone but when I'm in a PC I'll do so. However I'd like to point out that, when I posted my answer it WAS correct. The lack of quotes would have caused a fatal error. The OP has since been updated. Yet still no one has bothered to provide an actual answer.